# Queries about top command

Tags: linux, process, cpu, top

top command shows the process cpu utilization, and it when we sum the cpu utilization of all the processes then it goes greater than 100%. And how can it shows the cpu utilization of each process( app. > 300 process) in very short span of time. There is a question [about cpu usage by a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux)

that tells us to sleep for 1 second. And according to that solution Cpu usage by a process is different from top command output. so please tell me about right solution. My computer has the configuration Intel core2duo and ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

Top has two modes for computing the CPU load, one called Solaris mode, is counting the effective CPU load so with a two core CPU, the maximum load will be 200%. The other one is called Irix mode. It is showing the load divided by the number of CPUs, so the maximum shouldn't excess 100%. You toggle from one mode to the other with the "I" key.

Comment: So if we want to calculate cpu usage in "solaris mode" then we have to consider "cpu0" and "cpu1" entry separately. And I saw the source code of top implementation it uses hash table to retrieve results very fast. But is there another way to do this.

Comment: CPU usage reported in Solaris mode is as much correct as it is in Irix mode. What problem are you trying to solve ?